# Laravel eager loading with join on other table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, inner-join, eager-loading

can i change this code to syntax of has_many or has_one or ... to write beautiful code?

```
\App\User::with(['books' => function ($query) {
    $query->join('locations','books.location_id','=','locations.id')
    ->select([
        'books.*',
        'locations.name as l_name'
    ]);
}])->get()
```

Class User:

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should just have a Locations model which will have a relationship with Book model, and call it like this:

```
User::with('books.locations')->get();
```

This will give you the users with books and location of each book.

Comment: class Book extends Model
{
    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Location::class);
    }
} but error: Unknown column 'locations.book_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `locations` where `locations`.`book_id` in (1))

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
DB::table('users')
->select('books.*','locations.name as l_name')
->join('books','users.id','=','books.user_id')
->join('locations','books.id','=','locations.book_id')
->get();
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: OOPS! i want use eager loading